# Data Organizing in Python 3.4 3

Tags: python

In Python I am using this file Criteria.txt and it looks like this

```
Homework,5,10,10

Quiz,3,20,20

Midterm,1,50,30

Final,1,100,40
```

I typed in this code to open and manipulate the Criteria.txt file

```
criteria=open('Criteria.txt','r')
criteria_line=criteria.readline()



for criteria_line in criteria:
      print (criteria_line),
      criteria_myline = criteria_line.strip().split(',')
      print ("Assignment Type: "+criteria_myline[0])
      print ("Number: "+ criteria_myline [1])
      print ("Points: "+ criteria_myline [2])
      print ("Weight: "+ criteria_myline [3])
      print ()
```

The result was this

```
(None,)

Assignment Type: Quiz

Number: 3

Points: 20

Weight: 20

Midterm,1,50,30

(None,)

Assignment Type: Midterm

Number: 1

Points: 50

Weight: 30

Final,1,100,40

(None,)

Assignment Type: Final

Number: 1

Points: 100

Weight: 40
```

This was all correct except Homework didn't show up. You can see in the `Criteria.txt` file that Homework was the first assignment type in the list. What is wrong with this code? Why did it leave Homework out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you read the first line of the file *before* your for loop starts. This causes the cursor in the file object to move to the next line, so when you iterate through `for criteria_line in criteria`, you're excluding the very first line (the one that includes `Homework`). If you remove the line

```
criteria_line = criteria.readline()
```

it should work.

This all works because a file object is an iterable and python will iterate over the lines in the file by default.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
criteria_line=criteria.readline()
```

reads the first line, the one containing `Homework`. In the following `for` loop, you immediately discard this first result.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you `criteria_line=criteria.readline()`, you've already consumed one line from your file object `criteria` which is `Homework,5,10,10`, a fix is to read whenever you need the data in the `for` loop and as side note use `with` context opening file for better & safer coding:

```
with open('Criteria.txt') as criteria    
    for criteria_line in criteria:
        #print (criteria_line) #for debugging
        criteria_myline = criteria_line.strip().split(',')
        print ("Assignment Type: "+criteria_myline[0])
        print ("Number: "+ criteria_myline [1])
        print ("Points: "+ criteria_myline [2])
        print ("Weight: "+ criteria_myline [3])
        print ()
```